# Handle shared files like migrations between 3 different laravel projects

Tags: laravel

I have a scenario which is a little odd, i don't have a clear idea how to handle it. so let's say i have project which has 3 micro-services (3 different Laravel projects ) called : Admin, Agent and Front.

The real issue is with shared files such as migrations, seeders, factories even job queues ( My agent app handles all job queues) but let's say admin service dispatches those jobs to Redis and agent app takes jobs and handle them (another issue is here because i need to have those Job Classes in each laravel project because of file serialization in laravel job queue).

Temporary solution for me is to have them in both projects but i believe there must be better way to handle this. another issue is that each project has its own tests and those tests need migration, seeders and factories , i guess duplication of files is not a good idea here because day by day project grows and it becomes a mess one day. one possible solution i suppose is to have a git submodule . but i need your opinion here

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Job classess might be declared in a private package (i.e. hosted on your private git repository), and your projects can include them with `composer`.

Also migrations can be handled in package (see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#migrations) ) and I believe that you might also register Seeders and Factories there.

So I think the best solution is to have a package for those features shared by your 3 projects.

Comment: i believe maintenance cost is high here because we need to vendor:publish each time we make a tiny change to each class. imagine you are working on 3 projects at the same time. maybe the solution you proposed is appropriate but how to reduce development time in this case ?

Comment: You can symlink your package in your project, like `ln -sf /path/to/your/package ./vendor/yourname/yourpackage`.

so you can speed-up development and just make your commit on your package once you get a stable version.